# Is it possible to attached an ANTS Performance Profiler to an already running IISExpress process?

Tags: asp.net, .net, performance, profiler, ants

I'm trying to figure out how to attach an ANTS profiler to an already running IISExpress instance.

When I try to manually do that, it keeps saying that the port is already in use, which of course is obvious. But why is ANTS trying to start up a *new* instance when I just said *attach*?

Why do I want to do this? Because my start up is slow and yes, I know one can just highlight the area in the timeline that I care about, but I'm curious if this is possible none-the-less.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to connect to IIS Express the same as any other process.  Redgate's has a guide to setting it up [here](http://documentation.red-gate.com/display/APP8/Attaching+to+a+running+.NET+4+process).

All you should need to do is click the tab on the left that says "Attach to .NET 4 process", and pick out `iisexpress.exe` from the list.

It's not possible to add instrumentation to a process that's already been started, so you lose a lot of precision this way, as well as the ability to tie profiling data to individual requests.